# Spring WebFlux Post Issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using WebClient to do an API post but it is not returning anything. I'm assuming that the thread is staying open and not completing since I can use a block to get what I want but I'm still pretty new to WebClient and asynchronous stuff so I'm not 100% sure.

Specifically I have this method:

```
public Mono<AppDto> applicationPost(AppDto dto){    
   return webClient.post()
            .uri("/api/doStuff")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(MonoConverter.appDtoToMono(dto), String.class)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class))
            .map(MonoConverter::mapValueToAppDto);
}
```

Where MonoConverter does some conversion for mapping values so this should be irrelevant. The above returns a 202 Accepted but it does not return a value or hit my mapValueToAppDto method. The below however, does work:

```
public Mono<AppDto> applicationPost(AppDto dto){
    Map map = webClient.post()
            .uri("/api/doStuff")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(MonoConverter.appDtoToMono(dto), String.class)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class))
            .block();
    return Mono.just(MonoConverter.mapValueToAppDto(map));
}
```

I'm assuming that this works since it uses block but then a get method I have that is in a similar fashion works:

```
public Mono<AppDto> applicationGetOne(String appId){
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/getOne/{0}",appId)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Map.class))
            .map(MonoConverter::mapValueToAppDto);
}
```

I would prefer to use the first snippet since it does not use block and it's simpler and in the same format as my other methods.

Does anyone have any idea why the first one isn't working or know how I could get it to work?

Comment: This is a great sample demonstrating using WebClient: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/reactive-for-webmvc This was part of a talk from SpringOne and he explains in detail why we need to block or not. The video should be coming out soon

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ2SoXUiS7M

Comment: How are you subscribing to the Mono? And can you show a sample of what is being returned?

Comment: @TuhinKantiSharma Thank you for the video! It was very informative and makes me want to remove the blocking even more though I'm still not sure why what I am trying to do that is not working.

Comment: @KevH Do I really need to subscribe to it? With my other method that works I do not subscribe or block it but I do use it client side. I don't directly use the response for the method having the issue so could this be the problem? My only thought with this is that it is not even creating the object at my destination API.

Comment: @G.Blandin yes you need to subscribe, subscribe can simply be a client consuming, the above won't execute unless it is asked for. I suspected there was something else wrong with your code, I suspected it was how you were calling the code, glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why I was having this issue. It actual had to do with my controller 
 (D'oh!). For the post method, I have validation that binds errors so I was just returning a ResponseEntity without giving it a type. So I added a typing to the ResponseEntity and that fixed the issue.

e.g.:

```
@PostMapping(value="/post")
public ResponseEntity addThing(@Validated @RequestBody AppDto dto, BindingResult result){
    ...
}
```

And what fixed it:

```
@PostMapping(value="/post")
public ResponseEntity<Mono<?>> addThing(@Validated @RequestBody AppDto dto, BindingResult result){
    ...
}
```

I'm assuming that since at first the typing wasn't specified it wasn't using the thread the mono response was on and so I was never getting a response but by declaring the type, Spring knows to use the Mono thus allowing it to complete.